# ASP.NET Login, invalid password

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
    con.Open();
    string mysql; // generate an sql insert query for the database
    mysql = "SELECT 1 FROM [Users] WHERE Username=? AND Password=?";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", tbPass.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if(temp==1)
    {
        Session["LogIn"] = lblUser.Text;
        lblLogin.Text = "Welcome " + lblUser.Text + ", you are now logged in.";
    }
    else
    {
        lblLogin.Text = "Invalid Username/Password!";
    }
    con.Close();
```

Error: Syntax error in FROM clause.

"OleDbException was unhandled by user code."

Thanks.

Comment: Please use SQL parameters

Comment: @Benjamin No. Just no.

Comment: 1) Parameterize your queries. 2) Hash your passwords.

Comment: Read on SQL Injection, read on not storing plain text passwords, read on membership provider, in short get a good book on ASP.NET

Comment: visual studio comes with a very good debugger, why dont you step through the code?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? What is the value in `temp`? Whether or not the site is going live yet, I see absolutely NO reason not to use parameters instead of building queries how you are currently. You will only have to go back and change it if this mess ever does see the light of day and it takes less effort than your current approach.

Comment: You should never give a message "bad password only" because it will give a potention hacker the signal "so I guessed the username right"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

Now that I look closer there are many things wrong with this code.  Standard practice is to check for the username/password combination in one shot:

```
mysql = "SELECT 1 FROM [User] WHERE UserName=? AND Password=?";
OleDbCommand CheckUser = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
// Add OleDbParameters here with the correct type/length
CheckUser.Parameters.Add("@userName", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = tbUser.Text ;
CheckUser.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = tbPass.Text ;

int temp = Convert.ToInt32(CheckUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

and adding parameters to the command with the username and password values.  That way hackers can't determine valid usernames without knowing the password.

---

This block:

```
    mysql2 = "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Password='" + tbPass.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand Pass = new OleDbCommand(mysql2, con);
    string Password = Pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Will return the *first* column form the *first* row of the result set.  Unless `Password` is the first column in the `User` table, you're not getting the password back, you're getting some other value.

It could be:

```
    mysql2 = "SELECT password FROM [User] WHERE Password='" + tbPass.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand Pass = new OleDbCommand(mysql2, con);
    string Password = Pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: it will get interesting if some users use the same password :-)

Comment: @ChristopherDunne, I think it's more because it will save you heartache down the road. If you code in a big company with this kind of code, and a hacker uses *that* code to break into a system causing thousands of dollars/pounds/your favourite currency, in damage, guess who's jobs is on the line? Using your original methods can also get interesting with accents, special characters and those "funny" languages - using parameterised queries helps against that.

Comment: @ChristopherDunne One reason you're getting a lot of feedback about poor security (and many upvotes on the comments) is because **too many developers don't take security seriously**.  Whether your site is going live or not, your code is now visible to all the world.  It's like a cook on a cooking show burning food then saying - "It's OK, no one is going to eat it anyways."

Answer (score 0):

First, just because it builds doesn't mean it's right.

Second, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Third, without an error message or intent there's no way for us to divine what's wrong.

Last but not least: your code will only work if the first row of the first column obtained with the query returns a value of 1. I don't know what you're doing but if all else works for you, you may want to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it as :

```
con.Open();
string mysql; // generate an sql insert query for the database
mysql = "SELECT 1 FROM [Users] UserName='" + tbUser.Text + "' AND 
         Password='"+ tbPass.Text+"'";
OleDbCommand CheckUser = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(CheckUser.ExecuteScalar());
if(temp==1)
{
 //Login
}
else
{
 //Invalid UserName or Password.
}
```